# Are Eek and Oog living animals?

Tags: captain-future

In the 1978/79 anime TV series *Captain Future,* the robot Grag and the android Otho have pets: the pink Eek and the green Oog, respectively.

[image: Grag and Eek]

[image: Otho and Oog]

These pets mostly behave like real living animals; for example, they sniff around and chase each other. However, Oog is a shapeshifter similar to the android Otho, and in the episode *The Lost World of Time* we see that Eek is able to dive below the boiling surface of a young planet together with the robot Grag.

This leads me to the question whether Eek and Oog are really living animals or synthetic creatures like their masters.

Comment: In the source novel they're described (repeatedly) as animals.